# Web Api and web ui in same application/service

Tags: c#, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

For my AngularJS web application I use Azure Service Fabric as my backend. For that I created a stateless web api service.

Do I have to put the frontend /client-side AngularJS code in the same application type or the same stateless service? Is it useful to create another stateless service for the web ui?

Comment: I recommend to deploy (or manage) AngularJS code in _totally_ different project such as Azure WebApp rather than to put one of Service Fabric things.

Comment: @Youngjae I want to use two different projects. But I don't know if it is possible or useful to create two independently stateless services in Azure Service Fabric to seperate these things.

Comment: Why do you need Fabric for front-end file? Don't do that.

Comment: @Mikhail I use the microservice framework "Azure Service Fabric" to create a microservice application. And for that application I also have a web api service. As frontend I use angularJS. And my question was, If I can or should put the web api code and the frontend code in the same service?

Comment: @CPA I understand your question, but you haven't answered mine. The fact that you use Fabric doesn't mean you have to use it for everything, even for serving static JS files...

Comment: @Mikhail When I have an Azure Service Fabric application with a web api service, where should I else host my frontend code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can host your Angular web app anywhere you like; there are no restrictions imposed by Service Fabric in this regard.

That said, in your case a simple solution is to have your front-end web app and your web api in the same stateless service. Basically you treat this as a regular old ASP.NET MVC application, and ASP.NET MVC makes it fairly easy to have an API and web UI in the same MVC project. Here are a couple examples of this:

ASP.NET 5 MVC application with an API and a UI: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/Services/Chatter

Single-page jQuery app with an API self-hosted with Katana: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/tree/master/PartyCluster

As to the question of why do you need Service Fabric to host a front-end file. There are trade-offs here. Assuming the front-end is a web application that's meant to be part of a larger Service Fabric application - as it is in your case - it's nice to have everything in one place using one set of tools on the same SDK with the same deployment process hosted on the same cluster, rather than having a completely separate process, tools, SDK, and hosting environment for one part of your application. You also get all the Service Fabric goodness like rolling upgrades, health monitoring, high availability and auto failover, etc. The downside is that you don't get the super easy-to-use tools for web applications that come with, say, Azure App Service.

Comment: I will host the frontend app also in Service Fabric. Are there any performance issues if I use one stateless service for the API and one stateless service for the frontend app?

Comment: No issues that I know of. You may actually be able to increase performance if the two services have very different perf characteristics by restricting each service to a separate set of nodes designed to meet those charactistics.

Comment: But if I want to use two services, one for the api and one for the frontend ui, then I do need two OwinCommunicationListener right? One for each service. But then I will get problems, because both listen on the same port!?